# PHP - use Twig 2.x without composer

Tags: php, symfony, twig

To use Twig I went to [this](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/installation.html) and used git to download it.
Unfortunately I can't find any solution to import Twig to my project. At [this](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html) solution is only for composer but I don't want to use composer.
There is only the possibility to use the Autoloader.php at Twig 1.x 
Did I miss something?

Comment: Quick question; is there any particular reason why you don't want to use Composer?

Comment: when I try to install Composer I get two errors I can't fix:

`php composer-setup.php --disable-phar --with-openssl
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
`

Comment: What are those errors? Probably easier and better to fix those..

Comment: I know this is not addressing your question but why don't you want to use composer? In any case, I guess you'll have to implement your own autoloading strategy - I guess you can start by looking at `spl_autoload_register()`, assuming you're not using some other form of autoloading strategy in your code already.

Comment: I would recommend trying to solve the Composer issue instead...

Comment: @Husi012 fix the composer issue, if you have a new question we could help.

Comment: Also, you should include relevant parts of your code to more clearly illustrate what you are actually doing - this will give everyone a better shot and understanding and helping you with your problem

Comment: Create a new question for the composer issue instead of changing the context for this question in a comment. Include things like OS and  version, PHP version, how you tried to install it etc. We need to know step by step what you've done and tried.

Comment: I tried to enable openssl at the php.ini and php couldn't find the extension. Of course I searched for that problem but didn't find something

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay I'll do that, thanks

Comment: Therer are normally 2 `php.ini` file. One used by PHP under Apache and one for PHP CLI. Check which one is used by the CLI by running `php --ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I changed the file at '/etc/php7/cli/php.ini' which is shown when I run `php --ini` I didn't find another one.
By the way my OS is OpenSuse
@MagnusEriksson in one hour I will ask the new question

Comment: What version of PHP are you using.

Comment: I'm using php 7.1.8

Comment: Then it looks like your PHP was not compiled to include PHAR or SSL. Can you recompile PHP properly?

Comment: what do you mean with recompile? I reinstalled php but got the same result